# Object looses its scale on keyframe change

Tags: animation, objects, transforms

I've made a static model of a mannequin to do some tests.
My problem is that whenever I scale a part of the model, or the entire mesh, then every time I move the time-line a bit (or Alt middle mouse. I'm used to zooming that way from maya) the scaled meshes return to previous scale, along individual centers.

Here's a image sample of the problem:
1 Before the scale
[image: imaged]

2 After the scale (note the time-line)
[image]
3 After moving the time-line*
[image]

This effect would also happen if I'd scale the mesh, and then export it as a FBX (without moving the time-line).

I've tried to apply the scale onto the model. In effect the elements of the model get incredibly small, when the time-line moves/I export it.

I would be very grateful for any help with this issue.

*I know it wasn't exactly by 5. My mistake. But it's visible that the current time has changed.

Comment: like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTaR7jnJ1-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have part of your mesh animated. When you move the frame, it displays the current transformation of the keyframe with animation.

[image]

**Animated Frame**         **Current Frame**

You can fix this by going into the *dope sheet*, the *NLA editor*, or the *Graph editor*
And delete the unwanted animation
[image]

**You can click here to delete**                      **You can also select all the**

**the animation for that object.**                   **keyframes here and delete them.**

You can keep the transformation without deleting the previous keyframe by adding a new one and animating the transformation.